# Hierarchy of Convergence

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

My motivating thought is if I have a sequence of functions that converges in C([0,1]), is it enough to show that it converges to something outside C([0,1]), to show that it doesn't converge in C([0,1])? Limits are unique in metric spaces, so I suppose in this case it would be enough- but then what forms of convergence are stronger and weaker than other forms? For instance, almost uniform convergence doesn't imply a unique limit- we could have a function that almost uniformly converges to both a continuous function, and a discontinuous function! So what is the hierarchy of convergence, and when can I just cite the uniqueness of a limit?

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in [John D Cook's diagram relating modes of convergence](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/modes_of_convergence/). For example, in general, Almost Everywhere (AE), Almost Uniform (AU), Convergence in Measure (M), and LP convergence share the following relations:

[image: Modes of Convergence]

Here a straight line means convergence of one form implies convergence of another. A dashed line means convergence of the form from the root implies a subsequence converges in the other mode of convergence.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [this](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/02/245a-notes-4-modes-of-convergence/) post in Terry Tao's blog. From what I understand, there is no such hierarchy, but if a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ in one of the seven modes of convergence listed in Tao's post, and it converges to $g$ in some other (or the same as for $f$,) then $f$ and $g$ agree almost everywhere.